# Get data from accelerometer when application runs in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, background, accelerometer

So I need my iphone application to run in the background and collect data from the accelerometer. Even though I managed to do the former by playing background music, the accelerometer seems to stop sending data to the application when the app is not in theforeground.

Is there any workaround for this?

I've seen there's a trick to make it not go asleep:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

... but my problem is that I *have* to run and see the GUI of another application when this other one is running.

Thanks.

P.S. I know the app store would reject my application. My project is only for demostration purposes.

Comment: Actually, not only does the accelerometer not send any data, the GUI itself freezes until I put the application in the foreground again. The music keeps playing, though. Is this how it is supposed to be?

Comment: The accelerometer only passes on events to the app that's in the foreground. In other words, you're experiencing expected behavior.

Comment: You're not supposed to do UI updates when in the background.

Comment: OK, so neither the accelerator is sending data, nor the GUI is working. So what can the application actually do?

Comment: The only solution for this is to jailbreak your iPhone.

Comment: Argh. I just had the application write on a file whatever data its receiving from the accelerometer. Well, when in background mode the timer stops (so not only the label displayed on the GUI does) and it doesn't write anything at all. There are actually a few reads with the same accelerometer values on all axis, which I guess happens just before it is all put to sleep.  So, really, there is no solution for this?

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to do this? It's potentially a privacy problem and turns out to be a security problem — you can use the accelerometer as a keylogger.